# How to filter a lazy dataframe based on the n-to-last element of a column?

Tags: python-polars

My input is this :

```
import polars as pl

ldf = pl.LazyFrame({'CATEGORY': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
 'DATE': ['05/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '16/05/2023',
          '16/05/2023', '14/05/2023', '14/05/2023', '14/05/2023']})

print(ldf.collect())

shape: (9, 2)
┌──────────┬────────────┐
│ CATEGORY ┆ DATE       │
│ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str      ┆ str        │
╞══════════╪════════════╡
│ A        ┆ 05/01/2023 │
│ B        ┆ 05/01/2023 │
│ C        ┆ 05/01/2023 │
│ D        ┆ 05/01/2023 │
│ E        ┆ 16/05/2023 │
│ F        ┆ 16/05/2023 │
│ G        ┆ 14/05/2023 │
│ H        ┆ 14/05/2023 │
│ I        ┆ 14/05/2023 │
└──────────┴────────────┘
```

I want to collect the data based on the n-to-last element (let it be the second, here `16/05/2023`). The reason I can't hardcode it is that the parquet files I receive can have different dates and I'm only interested on the rows that correspond the second-to-last date.

A precision : I need to target the second-to-last group in the `DATE` (to be more precise).

To filter based on the last row (which belongs for sure to the last group), I can do `pl.last('DATE')` like below :

```
print(
    ldf
        .filter(pl.col('DATE') == pl.last('DATE'))
        .collect()
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬────────────┐
│ CATEGORY ┆ DATE       │
│ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str      ┆ str        │
╞══════════╪════════════╡
│ G        ┆ 14/05/2023 │
│ H        ┆ 14/05/2023 │
│ I        ┆ 14/05/2023 │
└──────────┴────────────┘
```

My expected output is this :

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬────────────┐
│ CATEGORY ┆ DATE       │
│ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str      ┆ str        │
╞══════════╪════════════╡
│ E        ┆ 16/05/2023 │
│ F        ┆ 16/05/2023 │
└──────────┴────────────┘
```

Can you guys tell me if it's possible to do that before using `collect` ?

Comment: Please tell me you're not really saving parquet files with dates as strings

Comment: Yes, the parquet I receive has the date column as `datetime64[ns]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the unique listing of dates in the column while maintaining order, [`unique`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.unique.html#polars.Expr.unique) provides us just that with a keyword argument.

From there, we just need to extract the element, here at index `-2`. Unfortunately [`Expr.get`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.get.html#polars.Expr.get) does not support negative indexing at this time, but we can work around this by converting the expression to a list with [`implode()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.implode.html#polars.Expr.implode), then use [`list.get`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.get.html#polars.Expr.get) which does support negative indexing.

Overall:

```py
ldf.filter(pl.col('DATE') ==
    pl.col('DATE')
    .unique(maintain_order=True)
    .implode()
    .list.get(-2)
).collect()
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬────────────┐
│ CATEGORY ┆ DATE       │
│ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str      ┆ str        │
╞══════════╪════════════╡
│ E        ┆ 16/05/2023 │
│ F        ┆ 16/05/2023 │
└──────────┴────────────┘
```

Addendums: Assumes dates don't repeat other than the one contiguous block they appear in. If this is not true, probably some type of `group_by` and transforming the DataFrame back is needed.

While this works, it does use the whole DataFrame to calculate all unique values, when ultimately we only want the `n-th` unique value, at second to last it feels like some technique starting from the bottom of the dataframe (or top if `n` was small at the top) would scale better.

Comment: To avoid lists, I think perhaps `pl.col("DATE").rle_id() == pl.col("DATE").rle_id().max() - 1` would be equivalent.

Comment: @jqurious that's a good one. If they can cause the files to be saved so that each date is its own row group then that would really make it optimal.

Comment: Even without that, if it's a big file with a lot of row groups then using pyarrow parquet reader would allow reading each group in reverse order. A lot of ifs and maybes on my part though.

Comment: Perhaps `df.join(df.unique("DATE", maintain_order=True).tail(2).head(1), on="DATE")` is actually better than `.rle_id()` as it doesn't assume contiguous input.